# Query not executing as expected, returns -1 no matter what

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I'm working on a user login system for a semester final. I am using C# in Visual Studio with ADO.NET. I have a query that I use on a database table named Credentials:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Credentials WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password
```

I also have the string connection as

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|UserCredentials.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
```

I then run the query against the table with `int count = selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`. `selectCommand` is the `SqlCommand` object with the above query in it. No matter what, count will equal -1 even if I enter an existing username and password. I want the count variable to be 1 when someone enters in a correct username and password combo.

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection() {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|UserCredentials.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
        );
        return connection;
    }
}

class LoginDB {
    public static bool IsUser(string username, string password) {
        SqlConnection connection = DatabaseConnection.GetConnection();

        string selectStatement = @"SELECT * FROM Credentials 
                                   WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

        try {
            connection.Open();
            int count = selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
            if (count > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And then finally in the login form when the user presses login (The message box is just a placeholder for now):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (LoginDB.IsUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("Logged in!");
        }
    }
```

Obviously this is just for a college project so don't say anything about how this is clearly an unsafe way to log users into a system.

Comment: Use `Execute` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, and count the number of records you get back.

Comment: Or change your query to return a count, and call `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but `AND Password = @Password` is *terrifying*; you should *never, ever* store passwords "as is" - they should be run through a suitable 1-way salted cryptographic hash (then you do the same 1-way hash on the test password; the hashes will match for an identical password, but you never need to *store* the password). Being a "college project" makes it a perfect time to learn how to do it *properly* :) (if you practice doing it the wrong way, it will become second nature to do it the wrong way)

Comment: Further notes in addition to @MarcGravell 's very important point:1.  [Bad habits: Using AttachDBFileName](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename) 2. [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) 3. You should dispose connection, command and reader with `using` blocks 4. Don't block the thread with a message box or complex calculations while the `SqlConnection` is still open 5. `SELECT` all the rows, or even a count, is not necessary, an `IF EXISTS` or `CASE WHEN EXISTS` will suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery is not what you want to execute. It is a query. You should use ExecuteReader which returns a SqlDataReader and then you can read how many rows are returned. Or ExecuteScalar will return only one column of one row.

Comment: That was it! I could have sworn that ExecuteNonQuery would work. Thank you!

Comment: @EthanNoble `ExectuteNonQuery` is for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements where you are changing the data. It returns the number of rows affected by the change.  `SELECT` does not change data, so there are not any rows affected.